# Табличная вёрстка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend, table

Имеется таблица 20х20. 
На каждом из столбцов таблицы нужно расположить фишку, которая занимает сразу две строки и при этом имеет три строчки текста, одна из которых должна попадать на разделение строк в таблице. При этом верхняя и нижняя часть фишки при нажатии должны вызывать разные функции. Как решить такую задачу?
Пробовал с абсолютным позиционированием и пересчетом координат в блоке для каждого элемента, но, мне кажется, это далеко не самое изящное решение. Пробовал так же брать за позицию элемента конкретную ячейку, при этом выползая за её границы вниз на высоту нижней ячейки. 
Может кто-то подсказать красивое решение?

[image: примерный внешний вид фишки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал для таблицы меньшего объема, но суть, надеюсь понятна...)

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

$('p').on('click', (e) => {
  const p = e.target;

  switch ($(p).text()) {
    case 'Text 1':
      sayHi();
      break;
    case 'Text 2':
      // do something
      break;
    case 'Text 3':
      sayHello();
      break;
  }

  $(p).css('color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
});

const sayHi = () => {
  alert('Hi!');
}

const sayHello = () => {
  alert('Hello!');
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

tr {}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}

p:hover {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div>
        <p>Text 1</p>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div>
        <p>Text 1</p>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div>
        <p>Text 1</p>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div>
        <p>Text 1</p>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div>
        <p>Text 1</p>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only **html/css**:

```html
<table style="border:1px solid #000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="20" colspan="3" align="center">
      1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10" width="10" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2" height="20" width="50" align="center" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
      2
    </td>
    <td height="10" width="10" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="20" colspan="3" align="center">
      3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: тут не only html) заинлайненный css также присутствует